# make 2D array more less in Java

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I have a Java code with 2d arrays and i want to rewrite this code to look like it has less code than i wrote before.

The main task of my code is to have cubes in 1.

Is there any ideas how to fix it?

**My Data:**

```
2 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

**My Code:**

```
 for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
                if(map[i][j] == map[0][3]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[0][4]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[1][2]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[1][5]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[3][0]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[3][2]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[3][5]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[3][7]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[4][7]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[6][2]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[6][5]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[7][3]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == map[7][4]) {
                    gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
    
              
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `cubes in 1`?

Comment: Considering that you always call `gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);` why do you need 13 `if`, instead of a single `if` where you verify the 13 possible conditions that should cause a call to `gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);`? Or better yet, abstract those 13 conditions in a single method and call it in your single `if`.

Comment: I'd say it draws the same rect over and over 13 times whenever `map[i][j]` is 1. And it only works with this particular data and no others. That doesn't look right to me. What is the actual definition of your task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are compairing every field in your map with every field in your map that equals `1`. So you could just check if the value of one field is 1:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == 1) {
                gc.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```